# Query Splunk using Power BI

Tags: powerbi, splunk

I would like to query Splunk real time using Power BI. what is the best method for querying Splunk with Power BI? Can it do it real time with no performance issues? Should I do it with REST  API calls? Do I create saved searches (based on biz requirements) and have PBI query the searches?  Can I make REST API calls in a dataflow that runs every five minutes to populate dataset and query the dataset?
[image]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in this use case? It *sounds* pretty inefficient from the initial description.

Comment: @warren.  We would like to create PBI dashboards against Splunk, preferably real time.  My understanding is that there are multiple ways to query Splunk, like REST APIs, or via ODBC connector against saved searches, or maybe loading the data into a database.  Just wondering how people build PBI dashboards against Splunk data, if it's even possible to query real time and get good response times, etc.  Hope that helps.  Any ideas on methods to do this?

Comment: You can "kinda" search 'real time' via REST calls ... but it *sounds* like a better option would likely be to have Splunk kick-out a CSV periodically you can PBI against. If you can better describe your use case, I suspect we can help you better

Comment: @warren.  Not sure how to describe this scenario better. There is a business need to produce some PBI dashboards on splunk data, where the dashboards look better than the ones produced by splunk.  No biz requirements exist currently other than cloning two splunk dashboards using PBI.  Users would like to see the data 'real time'.  If splunk can kick out .csv files, that may be an option, but can splunk refresh these files every few minutes?  And if the requirement is to see trends over the course of time (days/weeks/months/etc), wouldnt' the volume of the .csv files be big?

Comment: @warren I have added a screenshot (to my original post) of a splunk dashboard currently being used.  I am tasked with creating something like this against the splunk data using PBI.  I don't know splunk, but given this sample dashboard, and assuming it helps provide an idea of what we are trying to accomplish, what is the best way to create this?  API calls? .csv files? extract and load to database?  Hope this explains better

Comment: @warren I have been able to see the saved searchs in PBI and Tableau, but in both tools I get an ODBC 40 error 'unable to write to disk' when I try to connect to a very small saved search.  I'm thinking maybe this is because connecting to the saved search launches a query, and even if the result set is small, the execution of the query itself may be the problem.  Can splunk create a scheduled saved search that is static? i.e, where the results are written out to a static summary index/table table that a BI tool can connect to that doesn't actually execute a query when connecting to it?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing *a lot* more about your use case(s), specific advice is going to be difficult to give

However, you can easily hit the Splunk REST endpoint for saved searches, reports, and ad-hoc searches from anything that can speak REST with proper credentials/tokens

There are limits to how much data can be returned via REST, and if you're hitting it often enough with a large enough time window / slow enough search, you're going to start running into scenarios where Search A is still running when Search B gets kicked off